# react js call function from event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

How do i call a function from a react component inside the same class, I'm using create-react-app BTW.

```
Somefunction(){ //function
 return true;
}

handleClick(e){ // this works
 Somefunction(); // but fails here as Somefunction is undefined
}
```

I think i'm not binding it correctly, why is it undefined ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granted that you have bound the `handleClick` function to your class instance, you must access your `Somefunction` function on the instance with `this`.

```
Somefunction() { 
  return true;
}

handleClick(e) {
  this.Somefunction();
}
```

Comment: so obvious, why I didn't try that, excuse me while i go beat my self up, will accept when SO let's me, cheers Tholle.

Comment: @saj No problem, it happens to all of us.